# AFNetworking is getting information from webservice but as an error. Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016

Tags: ios, afnetworking

This is my code which is i am using for getting json from webservice

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:BaseURLString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =
    [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
                                                        NSLog(@"Dictionary   %@",(NSDictionary*)JSON);
                                                    }
                                                    failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
                                                        UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Weather"
                                                                                                     message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error]
                                                                                                    delegate:nil
                                                                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                                        [av show];
                                                    }];

    [operation start];
```

i am getting the correct information but in failure block like this

```
Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
    "text/json",
    "application/json",
    "text/javascript"
)}, got text/html" UserInfo=0xaa58030 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=" MYDATA in form of dictionary "
```

Can any one please guide me what is wrong with my code

Edit:

i have added this but no effect

```
[AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:
     [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your code, something is with your server side, it sends you the responce of type text/html, instead, of text/json or similar.
Check your server side, for example, if you try to access resource, which require authorization, you could receive an html error page instead of json data.

Comment: <?php header("Content-type: text/json"); ?> this solve my problem

Comment: Is there any method we can also get simple message from web service not in Json?